# How do you get to command mode on Cream Text Editor?

Tags: java, c++, vim, command, text-editor

I just recently installed cream, and I was wondering if there was a command mode to it, as it's a configuration of vim. Does anyone know how to access it?

Comment: Something like `:!/usr/bin/env bash` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, as I don't know where how to access the command mode for the text editor. Pressing `exit` won't work.

Comment: It might help if you told us what "command mode" was... try pressing ESC.

Comment: OOPS - I WROTE EXIT??? * `esc` won't work. My bad. Command mode is just normal mode for vim I believe, where you do things like `:w` and others

Comment: It's esc. In vim. No idea about cream.

Comment: I believe "cream" is the same as `evim` (easy mode), in that case you can use `Ctrl+L` to go to Vim Normal mode (then ESC or one of the usual insert/append commands to go back to Insert mode), or you can use `Ctrl+O` to enter a single Normal mode command and then stay in Insert mode once you're done with it.

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim (and I guess that includes "cream" if that's indeed the same as `evim`).

Comment: It really looks like "cream" is unmaintained at this point... While I can't confirm that `evim` is exactly the same as "cream", I think it's close enough. `evim` (or `vim -y`) already comes with Vim, so my suggestion is just install Vim/GVim/MacVim/etc. and use the `evim` version of it.